# Stack Exchange newsletter links don’t open in the app

Tags: support, ios-app, hyperlinks, newsletter

I have the app downloaded on my iPhone and I find it easier and smoother to use. The problem is in the Stack Exchange links from either the newsletter or when clicked on from an iMessage. I don’t have that problem in say, YouTube. I find that inconvenient, is there a way to get it to open in the app?